# Using Fetch: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript

I want to use the new Fetch in javascript to do an ajax request. This is the code I've written for that

```
// Example POST method implementation:
var initial_data = {
  'id': 1,
  'model-name': 'Joke'
};


postData('/start-jokes', initial_data)
  .then(data => console.log(data)) // JSON from `response.json()` call
  .catch(error => console.error(error))

function postData(url, data) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  return fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // must match 'Content-Type' header
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, same-origin, *omit
    headers: {
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
  })
  .then(response => response.json()) // parses response to JSON
}
```

but it throws an error on load like so

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Trying it out on the console this is the response also of calling postData

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Comment: Can you please show the log of your JSON string received from the server? This is occurring because your JSON string is malformed.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks Ullas I assumed it was the code with a bug but it was the backend throwing a 500 error and returning a django error instead of json

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `then(response => response.json()` in `fetchData` like this. If there is an error when you call API, you can't catch that.

```
// Example POST method implementation:
var initial_data = {
  'id': 1,
  'model-name': 'Joke'
};


postData('/start-jokes', initial_data)
  .then(response => response.json()) // parses response to JSON
  .then(data => console.log(data)) // JSON from `response.json()` call
  .catch(error => console.error(error))

function postData(url, data) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  return fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // must match 'Content-Type' header
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, same-origin, *omit
    headers: {
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
  })
}
```

Comment: Then how to get JSON response from fetch.

Comment: `postData` is just to declare the API call. You should control it outside when you execute.